# how to insert dynamic values in sql server via android

Tags: android, sql-server-2008-r2

```
public void query2(View V) 
  { 
      Log.i("Android"," MySQL Connect Example."); 
      Connection conn = null; 
      try { 
          String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"; 
          Class.forName(driver).newInstance(); 
          String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.0.2.2:1433/demo;integratedSecurity=true;user=usd;password=dell@123;";
           conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString); 
          Log.w("Connection","open"); 

    //  Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(); 
    PreparedStatement ps;
     ps=conn.prepareStatement("insert into UserMaster1 values(?,?)");
     //int x=stmt.executeUpdate("insert into UserMaster1 values( 'usaid','mansoori')");
     ps.setString(1,un);
        ps.setString(2,pwd);
     Log.d("exupdt","insertion done");
     Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    ps.executeUpdate();

                        Log.d("PreparedStmt","Success");
      conn.close();  
      } 
  catch (Exception e)
    { 
      Log.w("Error connection","" + e.getMessage()); }
  }

  }
```

i am inserting data in sql server by using the interface PreparedStatement by android to sql server but only a blank row inserted not the data how can i insert dynamic values

Answer (score 0):

**You cannot directly access your remote database.**

You have to write web-service on server side and then send request from your android application to this service.

You can use this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/) for example of implementing such program.

Comment: it is not recommended, but that does not mean you can't.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   private TextView t1,t2,t3; 
   private Button b1;
   private EditText e1,e2;
   String un,pwd;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    t3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv3);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
    e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed1);
    e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed2);

     if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT> 9){
          StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy =new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
          StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
}

  public void query2(View V) 
  { 
      un =e1.getText().toString();
      pwd =e2.getText().toString();
     if(un.equals("")||pwd.equals(""))
         Toast.makeText(this,"Above Fields cannot be left blank",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     else
     {
       Connection conn = null; 
      try { 
          String driver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"; 
          Class.forName(driver).newInstance(); 
          String connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://172.22.0.2:1433/Samay;integratedSecurity=true;user=DBSQL;password=samay@123;";
           conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString); 
          Log.w("Connection","open"); 
       PreparedStatement ps;
       ps=conn.prepareStatement("insert into UserMaster1 values(?,?)");
       ps.setString(1,un);
       ps.setString(2,pwd);
       int x;
       x=ps.executeUpdate();
      Log.d("exupdt",un);
      Log.d("exupdt",pwd);
 Toast.makeText(this, "Success"+x, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 Log.d("PreparedStmt","Success");
      conn.close();  
      } 
  catch (Exception e)
    { 
      Log.w("Error connection","" + e.getMessage()); }
  }

  }
```

}

My best friend solve this typical problem very logically i don't understand why you people don't give the exact answer instead of successions

my best friend name is s.(java queen) she simply solve this problem by giving

```
 un =e1.getText().toString();
      pwd =e2.getText().toString();
```

this code after the method query2 and program gives the exact result what i wanted ..i got dynamic insertion android to sql server...